# Calculate Session Duration based on LogFiles in Kibana

Tags: session, elasticsearch, kibana

I setup an ElasticStack and imported Millions of LogEntries. Each log entry contains a Tiestamp and a sessionID. Each session produces multiple log entries thus I have the following information available

SessionID   |   Timestamp

1234        |  stamp1
1234        |  stamp2
2223        |  stamp3
1234        |  stamp4
5566        |  stamp5
5566        |  stamp6
2223        |  stamp7

Now I would like to calculate the average/minimum/maximum session duration.
Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To do exactly what you want isn't going to be simple, I'm not even convinced it's possible with your data in its current form.

I'm also not sure what having the average, minimum and maximum session lengths actually gives you in terms of actionable information - why do you need the max/min/avg session times?

Something that could be easily visualised using you data would be session count against a date histogram. From Kibana, create a line graph visualisation. On the y-axis do a unique count of the session ID, on the x-axis select date histogram and use your timestamp field...

I would have thought knowing the session count over a period of time would give you a better idea for capacity planning than knowing max/min session times - perhaps you have already done this? This assumes each session is regularly logging... If you zoom in too far (i.e. between log events) the graph will look choppy, but it should smooth as you zoom out and there are options available for smoothing.